# Jetty graceful shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

A couple days ago I suddenly found out that Jetty graceful shutdown isn't working with SpringBoot automatically, Jetty server stops after Spring context already closed, so there is a lot of errors occurred in my application. So I had to write `@EventListener` on `ContextClosedEvent` to handle ordering of shutdown my services and stopping `JettyEmbeddedServletContainer`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyContextConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)
    public void shutdown() {   
        webApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainer().stop();

        myService1.stop();
        myService2.stop();
    }
}
```

With this code, Jetty Server is stopping at first, so there is no any new connection can be created and already received requests can be processed. But in this case Jetty doesn't send 2xx responses for some last received requests even if they are processed successfully. I got the error:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel     : /some/api/example

org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.reset(HttpConnection.java:677) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.access$300(HttpConnection.java:641) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:521) [jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:730) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:786) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:234) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:218) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:392) ~[jetty-server-9.4.7.v20170914.jar:9.4.7.v20170914]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1054) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:953) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What is myService1.stop()? In which of those lines does the error occur?

Comment: @MartinMeeser,  myService1.stop() perform some actions to carefully stop service, which actually send requests to DB. Error occurred when Jetty stops, it handles queue of requests (in QueuedThreadPool), but sends 5xx responses to client even though requests processed successfully (entities saved to DB). Raised exception is attached above